# Unexpected entry in a <select> field! How did this happen?

Tags: html, forms

In one of the forms on my website, I have a `<select>` field like this:

```
<select name="doorno" required>
            <option></option>
            <option>01</option>
            <option>02</option>
            <option>03</option>
            <option>04</option>
            <option>05</option>
            <option>06</option>
            <option>07</option>
            <option>08</option>
            <option>09</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>19</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>21</option>
            <option>22</option>
            <option>23</option>
            <option>24</option>
        </select></p>
```

The user should be able to select numbers between 01 - 24 - right?

But in the table where these entries are stored, I see an entry like:

```
01,05
```

How could this have happened? When I try to type into the field I am not able to it - I can only choose one of the options in the list?

Any idea how the user could have managed to enter an option like the one above?

**EDIT**
Based on some of the comments I looked into the backend of the database and found that the user has made multiple selections. So now the question has another related question:

If I do not specify the MULTIPLE attribute in the SELECT element, does it mean a user can overcome the default behaviour of single select?

Comment: Are you sure that the user is submitting it that way?  Could they be submitting 01 and 05 separately via different form submissions and you are concatenating them?

Comment: You understand that the HTML you have is ***totally*** unrelated to the PHP script? I mean you use them both together, but technically they are totally unrelated. It is the user who brings them together. And you as developer offer both in the strong hope, the user will understand how to use them together. However, if you take care when scripting, it's still you who needs to introduce the idiot checks.

Comment: @hakre - I like the way you said it - the part about "offer both in the strong hope" and "the idiot checks". However, I am a novice at this - very new to all the scripts and languages involved. As for idiot check - LOL I feel like the idiot here for not realizing that there could be situations where users might NEED to select more than one option! ...But you live and you learn! ....And of course, multiple selects leads me to new questions like how they will behave in SELECT queries!

Comment: Well you name two good points here: First of all not doing any idiot checks make oneself look like an idiot ( :D ) and second, how should you know what the idiot checks are if you're new. The best suggestion to this "unsolveable" looking scenario I can give is that you understand what your code does on the very fundamental level. That would be also asking a programming question. Clarify anything you need in your understanding, but first bring it down to the very fundamental problem(s). So understand how things work, then understand how your code is related.

Comment: Clarify the details, learn about about your own understanding. And lesson #1: Don't use code you don't understand. Always write it and find out how you can ensure it does what it should.

Answer (score 5):

Easy, the user has edited his DOM from the developer tools or using JavaScript. But fact is, this isn't the user's fault.

## It's yours!

You mustn't blindly trust input from the client, you should always validate that what you're expecting (in this case, numbers between 1 and 24), is what you're getting. In this case, it can be easily done with:

```
$input = (int) $input;
if ($input > 0 && $input <= 24) {
```

Always validate input. Always.

Comment: Given the incorrect input, your test will pass. In addition to testing that, you need to also cast the value to an int before you do anything else with it.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha - I am a little confused here.... I am using mysqli / php for sending the data to the database - no strip tags etc. So, if the user sent in a javascript, wouldn't the script they used also be stored in the field?

Comment: @vinaya: Validation != Sanitation. You sanitize (or rather, use prepared statements) to make sure the data won't break your query. You **validate** to make sure the data is what you expect it is (i.e. a number, and not a word or a range)

Answer (score 0):

At least two ways that it could happen: If you have or had another field with the same name in the same form, values from both will be submitted.  Also, if you ever had the MULTIPLE attribute on the SELECT tag, multiple values might have been submitted at that time.  (Although, for both these examples, how the multiple values get concatenated into the same database value is beyond the scope of this answer...)

Comment: When you say (Although, for both these examples, how the multiple values get concatenated into the same database value is beyond the scope of this answer...) - does that mean there IS a way for the values to have gotten concatenated, other than the user has editing his DOM or inserting javascript in the field?

Comment: since you mentioned the MULTIPLE attribute - I have never used it. From the http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6, I got this - "SELECT multiple    (multiple)     #IMPLIED  -- default is single selection --" for the SELECT element in FORMS. Going back to the backend of the database, it is clear that the user has made multiple selections on a field where the MULTIPLE attribute has not been specified.....Does not setting an attribute allow users to overcome default behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how it's possible, then it would be quite easy for a user to change the options in the select box from within their browser. Just a case of opening the dev tools and making an edit.

It's also possible for a hacker to post to your site without even using the HTML form, with completely made up data.

You should **never trust that data coming from the browser is valid**; always validate it again when it gets to your server before saving to the DB or doing anything else with it.