# If MULTIPLE is enabled for <SELECT>, how is searching based on that field affected?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

In my question in [Unexpected entry in a <select> field! How did this happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415501/unexpected-entry-in-a-select-field-how-did-this-happen/18415599?noredirect=1#comment27053551_18415599) , I had asked about an unexpected `01,05` entry in a field that stored values from a `<FORM><SELECT>`. The input did not have MULTIPLE enabled and should have had the default of single select.

Yet it allowed a user to make multiple selections. I have now realized that in my current scenario, there are several users who would need to select more than one option. So now I am faced with another question.

What if, I were to need to query the database for values in that same field? Would multiple entries stored in the field screw up the results?

Let us say that the `<SELECT>` asked the user to select between 01 and 04. My expectation would be that the field will store either 01, or 02, or 03, or 04 and I might query the table to return all rows that contained '02'.

What if one of the users has made multiple selections - say 02 and 04. In the database there would now be an entry like 02,04 in that field. If I were to query for 02 (or 04 for that matter), would I get the 02,04 entry in the result along with the ones that contained only '02' in that column?

What are the conditions under which I could face a select query that did not return all the rows I need?

Comment: Question - also with the other question - somehow is: What's your problem to learn about that by doing some research? Open-ended asking like *"What are the conditions under which I could face a select query that did not return all the rows I need?"* is especially discouraged here on the website because this leaves it open to many answers. But as you're new you likely will accept the first working one (or you seem to see working), it's really not well working this way. You don't get good answers is want I want to say.

Comment: Well! Starting from scratch 2 months ago, learned every line of code for HTML/PHP/MySqli by spending 2-3 hours everyday on SO, PHP.net and several others. Ditto for my two questions today. Does that count as research? I now have a live website with static and dynamic content, a mysql database with some 18 tables, user registration with hashed password, account approval, password reset, user segmentation and provisioning, etc. Most sites tell you how to do things. But none other than SO that answered specific questions/doubts when unexpected things happen - hence my questions here!

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I mean reasearch for the concrete question. Just an example: I do programming since years (20+) and PHP programming since PHP 3. When I've got a question - well when programming ca. 5-10 more concrete questions per day - I do research on those if I program well. So the difference between starting and the level of experience probably is the amount of questions you have and research you do. And rest assured it never ends. So it's not wrong at all to ask questions, I just placed a comment giving feedback what I think you can improve with it. Asking back is one method.

Comment: And if unexpected things happen, the journey begins where exactly the first time in which line of code is unexpected to you. Asking from the outside will likely not help you finding a duplicate question (e.g. I ask about a speficif website I'm right now programming that is about blue shells in red waters and then there is something wrong reporting the fluidities of the waters by colors database reuqest "not working" - this can not turn out well). Not saying you do it that way specifically, just saying, the exact opposite is most effective and will give you best answers.

Comment: Also it's perhaps not so easy to explain what I mean, so take my words with a pinch of salt it's not my first language.

Comment: Sure! I understand the reason behind the comment - and I won't take it wrong! I have seen for myself some of the questions that are asked - you can google with the exact question asked and get the perfect answer!....And of course - guilty as charged - no experience and jumped right in and offered to develop this website!...Only realizing now that I bit off what I have no hope of chewing :D. SO has been a lifesaver - even the caustic responses have pointed me in the right direction. There is just so much to learn and implement that sometimes it becomes overwhelming. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[MySQL IN Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)** to check whether a value is found inside a list of values.

A better approach perhaps, is to employ a single-to-many relationship table. (Look it up)